# How do I regenerate a resources file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, resources

This error appeared after moving my file across from different drives and updating the resources file. I'm not sure what is the root of the problem as I have removed all my resources and added them back. I have also tried removing the resources file and putting back the same copy. I'm not sure how to generate a new resources file to replace the one I currently have.
The error I get when running my application is this:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in "MyProject".exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Corrupt .resources file. Unable to read resources from this file because of invalid header information. Try regenerating the .resources file.

"MyProject" is just a substitution for my actually project name.

Comment: in solution explorer, **Show All Files** then open *My Project* then right click on `Resources.rex` and select **Run Custom Tool**

Comment: Did you mean Resources.resx if so I just tried selecting **Run Custom Tool** and nothing seemed to happen. It also didn't fix the problem.